# CiviMail *only some* Tracked Click Throughs not Redirecting properly

Tags: civimail, tracked-links

We have a problem with tracked click trough links ending up in a 404 Page not Found but ***only*** when the target URL ends in a hyphen.

e.g. we link to something like and end up nowhere:
https://mysite.eu/this-will-not-work-

while this works as intended: 
https://mysite.eu/this-will-work-all-right

Is anyone able to reproduce?

We are on Wordpress 4.9.x, PHP 7.0 and Civi 5.3 (and planning to upgrade real soon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was reproduced back in 2010: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7192

In short, this is a bug in CiviCRM that someone could fix, but it's very rarely triggered, and those who are affected haven't decided it was worth investing in the fix.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up. We better make sure not to use URLs ending in a hyphen then